# Datatypes in c#

Tags: c#, types

I am in need of an integer data type which starts with 00 from 1 to 10 and 0 from 10 to 99.

Is there any data type in c#

Thank you very much....

Answer (score 7):

You can use pretty much any integer type for that(`int`, `uint`, etc); the important part is how you *format* it. In this case:

```
string s = i.ToString("000");
```

The integer data type is *just* the value - leading zeros don't exist *or not exist* - simply that isn't the job of an integer.

You could always create a custom `struct` of course, taking the integer value in the constuctor (and maybe a custom conversion operator), overriding the `ToString()` method (and probably `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, etc).

---

Just for kicks:

```
public struct TriDigit : IComparable, IComparable<TriDigit>, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<TriDigit>, IEquatable<int>
{
    private readonly int value;
    public TriDigit(int value)
    {
        if (value < 0 || value > 999) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        this.value = value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString("000");
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (obj is TriDigit) return ((TriDigit)obj).value == value;
        if (obj is int) return ((int)obj) == value;
        return false;
    }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return -1;
        if(obj is TriDigit) return value.CompareTo(((TriDigit)obj).value);
        if (obj is int) return value.CompareTo((int)obj);
        return -1;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public static explicit operator TriDigit(int value)
    {
        return new TriDigit(value);
    }
    public static implicit operator int(TriDigit value)
    {
        return value.value;
    }

    int IComparable<TriDigit>.CompareTo(TriDigit other)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(other.value);
    }
    int IComparable<int>.CompareTo(int other)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(other);
    }
    bool IEquatable<TriDigit>.Equals(TriDigit other)
    {
        return value == other.value;
    }
    bool IEquatable<int>.Equals(int other)
    {
        return value == other;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a format string, not a data type.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D3}", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `int` or if it must not be negative `uint` (unsigned integer). There are smaller data types, but for most applications they're not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you need an integer with a legal range from 1 to 10, with an index that starts at zero, then the answer is no.  You'll need to make your own an ADT for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's formatting you want, not a new datatype.  Read all about it here: [MSDN's page on Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar) like..

```
int myNumber=12
string myStringNumber = myNumber.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
```